# Python Poetry, install project into shell's namespace

Tags: python, python-poetry

What is a / the proper way to install Python programs into the shell's namespace via Poetry? With `setuptools`, you can use `$ pip install -e path/to/project` and then you can invoke `$ project`. However I have not found a way to do that with Poetry. Instead I need to use `$ poetry run project`.

To clarify, I want the following behavior:

```
$ poetry <some command> path/to/project
$ project
<output of project>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the shell's namespace"? Install a script in your `PATH`?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your goal is to install your cli and make changes to it without having to reinstall it?

As you've probably noticed `pip install -e` doesn't yet support PEP 518 based projects like you get with poetry.

Poetry's solution for this is of course to let you execute installed libs or cli tools with `poetry run` as you described, or to activate the virtualenv that poetry creates containing your project in a new shell with `poetry shell`, which is similar to an interactive installation as long as your stay inside that shell.

Of course you can still install the project as usual with `pip install .`, and mess around with the files as the installed location, though this isn't a recommended workflow.